# Cannot move from one tab to the other in iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4

I have an application that works well in iOS 5, but when I try it in iOS 4 I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  I have a a tab bar that is added in the AppDelegate as follows:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:NO];

UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];

searchTableViewController = [[SearchTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *navControllerSearch=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchTableViewController];

firstviewcontroller = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] ;
UINavigationController *navFirstView=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstviewcontroller];
[[FirstViewController tableView] setScrollEnabled:NO];

secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
UINavigationController *navsecondView=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[[SecondViewController tableView] setScrollEnabled:NO];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navFirstView, navSecondView, navControllerSearch, nil]];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

When I try to move from the first tab to the second the app crashes. In iOS 5 it works well. iOS deployment target property is iOS 4.0.

If I run Instruments and look for Zombies, I can find a Zombie with the following info:

```
#   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible      Library    Responsible Caller
1   0x5a21880   CALayer Zombie  -1  00:10.816.545   0   QuartzCore  -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:]


0 CoreFoundation ___forwarding___
1 CoreFoundation _CF_forwarding_prep_0
2 CoreFoundation CFRetain
3 CoreFoundation +[__NSArrayI __new::]
4 QuartzCore -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:]
5 CoreFoundation -[NSObject(NSObject) copy]
6 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy)  _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
7 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
8 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
9 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
10 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
11 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
12 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview]
13 UIKit -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:]
14 UIKit -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:]
15 UIKit -[UITransitionView transition:toView:]
16 UIKit -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:]
17 UIKit -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:]
18 UIKit -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:]
19 UIKit -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the code in the second ViewController , maybe something is crashing you on load, it seems like the crash happens after the transition is complete.
try debugging you viewWillApear or viewDidLoad.
Does the other tabs crash too ?

Comment: Yes, the other Tabs crashes too. viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad are not executed (it crashes before that)